# You must register ParseObject subclass before instantiating it - Error fix?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am new to Android and Parse. Could some one please help me with this.

I am getting this error - 'You must register ParseObject subclass before instantiating it.' as soon as I click the submit button for my user creation.

Here's the class for creating a new user

```
package course.examples.gosportsathletetracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.SumPathEffect;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import java.text.ParseException;

public class Create_New_Account extends Activity {

    public Create_New_Account(){

    }

    protected Button Submit;
    protected EditText NameField;
    protected EditText DOBField;
    protected EditText EmailField;
    protected EditText PasswordField;
    protected EditText Sport;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create__new__account);

        NameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_Name);
        DOBField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_DOB);
        EmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_New_Email);
        PasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_New_Password);
        Sport = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter_Sport);
        Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);

        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = NameField.getText().toString();
                String dob = DOBField.getText().toString();
                String email = EmailField.getText().toString();
                String password = PasswordField.getText().toString();
                String sport = Sport.getText().toString();

                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.put("athletename", name);
                user.put("dateofbirth", dob);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.put("sport", sport);

                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(Create_New_Account.this, "Sign-Up Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Create_New_Account.this, Main_Menu.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Create_New_Account.this, "Sign-Up Failed, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

and this is the other class

```
package course.examples.gosportsathletetracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class ParseWorkshopApplication extends Application {
   @Override
    public void onCreate(){
       super.onCreate();

       Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
       Parse.initialize(this, "6yj7dATJU23N6okEKtJg94pXT5N55TwjhwSZRhnK", "CDDUf31ACn4lMXLxY0R2rByZ3zV9f2o2FT7YDO3x");

       ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

       defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
       ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
   }
}
```

and here's my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.examples.gosportsathletetracker" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/applicationicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Launch_Screen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login_Screen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login__screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Create_New_Account"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_create__new__account" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Drink_Food_Intake_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drink__food__intake__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Food_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_food__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Breakfast_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_breakfast__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Lunch_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lunch__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Dinner_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dinner__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Drink_Menu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drink__menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Competition_Performance"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_competition__performance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Supplement_Intake"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_supplement__intake" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please do help me out.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658383/parseexception-you-must-register-this-parseobject-subclass-before-instantiatin

Comment: Philipp, I already had a look at that one, was not able to understand it. 

It would be helpful, if someone could tell me the specific solution, with regard to my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
Parse.initialize(this, applicationId, clientKey);
```

in your `onCreate()` method